# Using WITH in sql query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, order-by

I am trying to replace `#` with numbers, but the `order by` is being ignored, and I was told to move the subquery using`WITH` or adding a limit to the `order by`, I tried the latter but it didn't work, and I am not sure how to use `WITH` in the following query.

```
update items
join (select id, @num := @num + 1 as num
    from items, (select @num := 0) items
     where parent_id =  159133    order by name) items2
on items2.id = items.id
set items.description = replace(items.description, '#' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, cast(num as char(10))) 
WHERE parent_id = 159133 and type='photo';
```

Comment: `WITH` is implemented since mysql v8 (mariadb v10.2.1) so for mysql-5.7 CTE isn't an option.

Comment: What is the real question behind the post? Why are you trying to order by in an update? To add an id value sequentially?

Comment: @Kondybas So, is there another way to do it in that version?

Comment: @Jacob H, should the `order by` be moved from the `update`? Can you explain how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query can be written without subqueries/joins like that:

```
UPDATE items
   SET description = replace(description, '#', cast(@num:=@num+1 as char(10))) 
 WHERE parent_id = 159133 
   AND type='photo'
   AND @num := 1       -- @num initialization by Akina
 ORDER BY name ASC
;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gave this error: ` #1270 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT), (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'replace'`

Comment: @Mike May be the difference in collations between the server and the table cause that error. Just use the explicit `COLLATE` as you did before.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to `description, '#' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`, and the `num=0` and it worked!  It just gives this error `MySQL returned an empty result ' for 'SET @num = 0`, but it worked..

Comment: To obtain single query one can move the initialization of `@num` variable to WHERE clause by adding `AND 1 = (@num := 1)`.

Comment: @Akina You are absolutely right! That works because of clause precedence. I've changed my answer. The only suggestion - it can be shortened to the `AND @num := 1` as far as result is non-zero/NULL.